Setting Base class member's value from derived class's setvalue function
Is there any mechanism like super in java in C++ to set base class variable value .
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class Base
{
    protected:
    int a;
};
class Derived: public Base
{
    public:
    void setvalue(int a)
    {
        a = a;
    }
    int getvalue()
    {
        return a;
    }
};
int main()
{
    Derived d;
    d.setvalue (23);
    cout<<d.getvalue()<<endl;
}

I tried the upper testcase to run but could not get the expected output.

a = a; will set the parameter a to the value of the parameter a.  Having a parameter shadow a member variable name is worth avoiding, in my opinion.

if you can't find a different name, at least tell compiler that you mean the member of the class this->a = a;

Please don't edit the code losing the question mind. You've changed it and made another mistake.

I rolled back the last edit because a question should not be changed to invalidate existing answer(s).

Another convention is to tag member variable names with some pre/postfix e.g. a_ or m_a this helps avoiding the shadowing mentioned before.  (using this-> is then also not necessary)

It is not a keyword, but you could easily do using super = Base; in the derived class. More useful when the base class name is a bit more complex, like a template.

setvalue will not assign a to this->a. It will assign the function parameter a to itself. Either use this->a = a; or better, don't shadow the member variable and give the function parameter a different name:
void setvalue(int arg) {
    a = arg;
}

In your updated question, you have added a to Derived too. In that case, you can access the base class a via Base::a:
class Derived : public Base {
    int a;

public:
    void setvalue(int a) { Base::a = a; }
    int getvalue() const { return Base::a; }
};


Is there any mechanism like super in java?

Not exactly. You'll have to spell the base class name out. C++ supports multiple inheritance, so being explicit about what base class you mean is a good thing. Example:
class Base1 {
protected:
    int a;
};

class Base2 {
protected:
    int a;
};

class Derived : public Base1, public Base2 {
    int a;

public:
    void setvalue(int a) { Base1::a = a; }     // what would super mean here?
    int getvalue() const { return Base1::a; }
};


Actually I dont want to change my variable name.

@GauravLodhi Then, change the member variable name - or use this->a = a; as I mentioned. Note that shadowing member variables may get your code rejected by static analysis tools that you may get subjected too in the future.

@GauravLodhi I see that you updated the question, so now the issue is different. You now have 3 as, which is not a good idea, but you can still access the base class a as I show in my updated answer.

@GauravLodhi Did I answer your question or is there anything you'd like me to clarify?

@TedLyngmo I rolled back the edit because a question should not be changed to invalidate existing answer(s), but then I saw you updated your answer for the change. Sorry if I messed it up. Not sure if the my rollback should actually be cancelled.

@wohlstad No worries. You are right, the question shouldn't change so that existing answers become invalid and there is another answer to consider - and I think my answer still works even though it now also talks about something not included in the question anymore :-)

The problem is that function parameter name "a" hides the name "a" is the base class. So the assignment in setvalue merely assigns the function argument to itself.
Your options are:

Rename Base::a to Base::m_a. Pick any other coding style convention if m_a doesn't look good.

    void setvalue(int a)
    {
        m_a = a;
    }


Rename function partameter to arg

    void setvalue(int arg)
    {
        a = arg;
    }


Prefix class member access with this->. This syntax is mostly useful in templates.

    void setvalue(int a)
    {
        this->a = a;
    }


Actually, I dont want to change the name of the variables and I want to change the parent class variable not the same class with this keyword
